# jssc doesn't receive a signal

Tags: java, event-handling, serial-port

i've got to handle a serial communication between a client and a server in java and on windows platform.
i am using the JSSC lib (tried 0.9 and 2.6), but I've got the problem that I can't receive data.
I am using a virtual bridging software for emulating a nullmodem device connection (http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-virtual-serial-ports).

the ports itself are opened with default parameters (9600, 8, 1, 0).

if i am using the hyperterminal software of microsoft i can see that the data is sent and received in bidirectional ways.
on the other hand if i am trying to communicate with two eclipse projects, whereas one send a signal (`writeBytes()`) and the other receives the signal (`readBytes()`), the signal won't make it to the `readBytes` method.
i only get `null` as return value from the `read` method. 
for the signal itself i've tried from `byte[]` to `string` with and w/o `\r\n`.

OS: WIN7_x64

what am I doing wrong?

feel free to ask if some information are missing or sth. is unclear.

kind regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the main problem by deinstalling the emulation software for virtual com-ports and re-installing it properly with admin-rights and 
`bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON`.

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke `readBytes()` method without parameters jSSC try to read all available data from serial port, if serial port input buffer is empty method returns immediatly with `null` value.

For correct handling incoming data you should to use `SerialPortEventListener` interface, the example of code:

```
class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {//If data is available
            int bytesCount = event.getEventValue();
            System.out.print(serialPort.readString(bytesCount));
        }
    }
}
```

You should assign an object of SerialPortReader type to your serial port object, like that:

```
serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader());
```

The another way is to use a loop with read method inside it, something like that:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        if (serialPort.getInputBufferBytesCount() > 0) {
            System.out.print(serialPort.readString());
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.prinln(ex);
}
```

But I strongly recommend you to use `SerialPortEventListener` because it run in a standalone thread and use a serial port specific API.

Comment: Hi, I already used the code of your first+second code block before.
When I debugged it the `serialEvent` wasn't triggered, so I looked down further and saw that the `readBytes` return value was `null`.
This is what I described in the original post. After removing the Listener I used a modified version of your third code snippet.